# Get rid of [suggestions], [advice], [recommendation] and likes

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-block-request

The following tags need cleanup:

- [suggestions](/questions/tagged/suggestions): 233 questions. Some questions need to be retagged to [search-suggestion](/questions/tagged/search-suggestion) or [autosuggest](/questions/tagged/autosuggest); pure polls need to be retagged to [polls](/questions/tagged/polls) (and closed as *Not Constructive* or voted for deletion, if not done yet). For the remainder, just remove the tag altogether. I already worked through the first 50 questions. **Update**: I worked through another 100 questions (there are currently only 82 left), but I ran out of close votes for those which are clearly non-constructive, so other day I will continue.
- [suggestions-wanted](/questions/tagged/suggestions-wanted): 26 questions. I've already removed the tag from all the questions, but please burninate it.
- [advice](/questions/tagged/advice): 121 questions, 100% meta tag. It needs definite burnination. **Update**: some of them which is related to AOP might need to be retagged to [aop-advice](/questions/tagged/aop-advice) or something.
- [recommendation](/questions/tagged/recommendation): 354 questions, 100% meta tag. Most of the closed questions, especially the pure poll ones with high votes, should be retagged to polls; then the tag can be burninated.
- [recommendations](/questions/tagged/recommendations): 5 questions. It has been already removed.
- [review](/questions/tagged/review): 79 questions. I see very little abuse, but this tag doesn't feel right. Some of them needs to be retagged to [code-review](/questions/tagged/code-review) (which might need to be migrated to codereview.se at some point).

Comment: Are you sure that "advice" isn't part of some AOP questions, where it would definitely not be meta? (metaprogramming concepts are not "meta")

Comment: e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042918/aspectj-is-it-possible-to-catch-execution-of-an-advice and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026228/policy-enforcement-to-add-a-new-item-aspectj

Comment: @Mark: could you please create a clear tag wiki and remove the tag from questions where it is irrelevant?

Comment: Not sure I'm qualified to write a tag wiki on the subject, but I can try to clean it up a bit.

Comment: @Mark: Or, likely better, maybe a new tag? `aop-advice` or something?

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on this. Several of these require some thought. 'advice' is real in AOP. 'recommendation' can be real for a recommendation engine (c.f. Apache Mahout). Etc, etc. It requires reading each question.

Comment: Yes, it's a lot of work. As to the recommendation engine, good point, I think `recommendation-engine` is a better tag then.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that seems extreme (and a whole lot of work).

I don't think [recommendation](/questions/tagged/recommendation) is a meta tag, ALL tags are meta information, and there are `rec` tags used a lot on other sites like SU and Webapps.

I like more their more specific ones like `software-rec` and `webapp-rec`, and think you could make some more specific ones for SO like `library-rec` or `ide-rec` etc.

**Not everything that has more than one possible answer is a poll.**

Not every list is a poll.

A poll is where the OP is looking for 'best', as opposed to just looking for some resource (which I usually tag [resources](/questions/tagged/resources)).

Comment: I did not mean *all* questions tagged recommendation. Mainly just the closed ones. I've edited the question to clarify that bit a bit more.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer a little.

Comment: Last time I checked, Recommendation questions were poor and/or subjective and most of them abused the community as cheap search-machine.

Comment: @PaddedCell, so maybe the recommendation tag is useful so you can ignore any quesions with it....

Comment: @Padded, yes, a lot of them are, but there are lots of crappy syntax questions also.  I don't see what's wrong about someone asking for a specific library that will do their job.

Comment: Evaluation should be *their* job, not ours. We can only point them to known resources (therefor, poll) and not recommend the best solution for them. If somebody [pops up like that](http://serverfault.com/questions/310623/sql-server-vs-mysql-vs-oracle-for-a-large-government-project), I always get the chilly feeling that something is wrong in the world and want to tell them to get someone who knows what he's doing.

Comment: @Padded, I'm not talking about evaluation as the purpose of the question, though answerers might do that.  I'm talking about __Identification__; lots of times they just need to know what libraries are available.

Comment: I'm not insinuating that everything that has more than one possible answer is a poll. Only non-constructive open-ended questions are polls. As to the `[recommendation]` tag, maybe it's a better fit for those questions which **are** constructive, but then I'd wonder if that wouldn't better belong in programmers.se.