# What tags for a totally off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, tags, off-topic

I spent some time trying to be helpful for [Get rid of [suggestions], [advice], [recommendation] and likes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109074/get-rid-of-suggestions-advice-recommendation-and-likes).

Many of the questions here are so far off-topic that there should be no possible tag for them. All their tags were either 'meta' or billboards for their off-topic nature.

I was a bit puzzled, thus, as to what tags to leave on them, particularly the ones that were already closed.

Comment: We could introduce a [`[無]`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29) tag...

Answer (score 18):

Since this old Meta post was mentioned here on English Language & Usage Meta: [What tag should be used when a question is completely off topic?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13718/116151), I feel it's worth providing an update: adding [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) to a question (as was mentioned in a now-deleted answer here) is no longer possible, at least [on most sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352726/295232):

[image]

(if you see it in the wild, that's because it's [automatically applied under certain circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167879/295232))

IMHO, a good rule of thumb is that if there's no applicable tag for an off-topic question, it's probably better deleted, so it doesn't matter which tags it has; just leave the current ones as that is the least amount of work.

Comment: @Rob there are other reasons, such as tag pruning, and it's not just moderator who migrate questions. It *might* be worth adding this information, but it's better to be complete and link to an FAQ (if there is one) than just mentioning one possibility.

Comment: I will just mention that a mod can *merge* another tag into (untagged). (Of course, this is not an option for regular users.) See quid's comment under this question: [Burnination vs. merging into a specific tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309327). (The same question mentions two sites which have a tag that can be used for off-topic questions - but that doesn't seem to be an optimal solution.)

Comment: Here's a [relevant canonical post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167880/377214). I should also add that the tag has to be manually blocked on each site separately, so there are still some [sites on which the tag hasn't been blocked yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352726/377214).

Comment: This started out as an improvement to a [suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/83577), that we improve it is where there's the greatest benefit.

Comment: It's really not an improvement to a suggested edit, as my suggested edit has nothing to do with when untagged gets added. Personally, I agree with Glorfindel that discussing when [tag:untagged] gets added is off-topic here.