# What causes a question to be tagged as [untagged]?

Tags: discussion, tags, faq-proposed, untagged-questions

I had thought that any question tagged [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) was as a result of migration. But 
[What happened to the village in Contagion?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5921/what-happened-to-the-village-in-contagion) was not migrated from anywhere as far as I can tell, so how did it end up untagged? Perhaps it was asked by someone with the tag creation privilege, but after a long enough time with only one question, the tag went away? What are the various ways that a question can end up tagged as [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged)?

Also, can a tag be added to such a question, or must [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) be removed when another tag is added?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, a migration cannot occur if it does not have at least one tag that's present on the target site.

Comment: @animuson is correct. Moderators, however, can migrate anything to any site regardless of applied tags, provided that the question itself is not too old to migrate - so it's always good to check the question history to be sure.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### What are the various ways that a question can end up tagged as [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged)?

Tags that only exist on one question are automatically removed after 6 months ([12 months on meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341923/295232)) by a monthly script, unless [someone has written or proposed a wiki for the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki) (including [rejected proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325125/single-use-tags-with-no-tag-wiki-but-with-rejected-proposals-for-the-tag-wiki)). As well, tags are sometimes removed through Meta discussions; staff members can remove any tag from the system in response to a discussion. If a question uses only one tag that is removed as a result of these actions, this will leave the question [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged).

Additionally, if a question is migrated from another site, and none of that question's tags exist on the destination site, the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag will be applied. Ordinarily, such migrations are blocked, but migrations performed by moderators of the origin site bypass this check, and the check is also bypassed if the question uses a tag that is considered "intrinsic" to the destination (e.g. [graphics](/questions/tagged/graphics) where Graphic Design is the destination). (This does not apply if the destination site is a meta site, in which case it will get the tag [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).)

### Can the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag be added to questions, or must it be removed when another tag is added?

The [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag is [blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295149/377214) network-wide, so you cannot add it to any question, and if you edit a question that uses it, you'll be prompted to remove it.

You should periodically check for untagged questions and retag them (or close/delete them if necessary).