# A moved question lost tags

Tags: support, tags, migration

I wrote a question on a Stack Exchange site, only to find out that a few hours later, it was moved to another site in the Stack Exchange network.

It's OK, but when the question was moved, the tags I assigned at the moment of writing were lost.

I tried to edit, only to find these tags or similar are not available on the site where the question was moved into.

Should I ask a moderator or administrator to add them manually? Then how can I do that?

Comment: Tags are specific to an SE site. Tags on one site are not relevant to another site. Even if both sites have tags with the same name, the tag definitions could be different on the two sites.

Comment: thank you, that's natural, only it appears to be as bug -- to leave it upon me and give no option to introduce them (as I have next to none reputation) and no button to ping admin or queue for additional review.

Comment: Well, your question was migrated because it was likely off topic on the site you originally posted it on and is on topic on another. While it would be nice, not all moderators are able to edit your question after migration to ensure it has the best tags. You can join the site yourself and edit it, though.

Comment: Each site has a Meta for you to ask questions about the site, and you can certainly ask for new tags there.

Comment: Is [this](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/28489/ocd-or-transgender-or-mix-of-them) the question you refer to?

Comment: yes, I might have an opinion about relevance, but I'm not moderator to decide. yet, I find it somewhat awkward and causing annoyance.

Comment: @ayvtill - You will have to accept that community moderation is part of being a productive user of the community

Comment: that's what I do.

but my question lays between psychiatry (which is medicine because it deals with biological deficiencies) and psychotherapy/psychology (which is more from soft categories of mind issues).

and while I accept moderator rule as absolute, I find it tossing me into corner without rights and offloading design bugs as problems on me. this should be discussed.

I'd consider rather correct to move tags as proposed to new place - they do fit here by semantics. that's not a case at the moment.

Comment: Ultimately, this is not a bug and is [tag:status-bydesign]. When a question is migrated, tags which don't exist on the target site are removed, not created. This is an intentional decision on the part of the software designers. As mentioned above, tags exist on a per-site basis, and are always something which is decided upon by higher-reputation users and/or moderators as to if the existence of a tag on a particular site is appropriate. Given that the typical reputation requirement for creating tags is 1500 rep, it wouldn't be appropriate for tags to be created by migration.

Comment: It answers my question, but I find previous comment "this is not a bug and is status-bydesign" as bug tracker answer WONTFIX/WHOCARES (or lacking of acceptance at least). So, yes I marked answer as valid (because it is) but I don't accept attitude. After nearly 40 years in software industry it tells a lot about process improvement. Thank you for minimal support tho - it works just fine.

Comment: Quick note is that Makyen is a user just like you (here on MSE at least). We have no power or influence on what SE, Inc. decides to do or not do, or when for that matter. As asked, your question is perfectly answered by the proposed duplicate targets, which is the purpose of duplicate closure on the network (not to provide support but to guide future users to canonical sources). Feel free to start a feature request arguing for the revisiting of the process as a separate question.

Comment: thank you, this sounds way more pragmatic and positive towards action.

Comment: @ayvtill While I understand you didn't have a good experience, adding [tag:status-bydesign] (effectively, WONTFIX) and duplicate closure is the appropriate response to a *bug report* about something which is working as designed and intended and which is described in the FAQ questions. What could be quite beneficial is to improve the process such that other people don't have as negative an experience. Doing so could be started by you creating a new [tag:feature-request] question which asks for improvements, at least in how things are communicated.

Comment: One thing which appears clear in this situation is that having the post notice at the top of your migrated question directly link to the above linked FAQ question which describes migration was insufficient with respect to communicating to you that this is how the system works (regarding tags) and what you can do about, potentially, getting appropriate tags on your migrated question. If you could provide suggestions as what might be effective at communicating that information to you, it would be helpful to include those suggestions in any [tag:feature-request] question which you might create.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is not a bug.

Each site has its own set of tags, so naturally you will not find all tags of site A in site B, and vice versa.

Upon migration, tags that don't exist on the destination site are removed. If no tags are left, the system automatically assigns the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag, as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167879/what-causes-a-question-to-be-tagged-as-untagged). The moderator who migrates the question might edit to add relevant tags, but they are not obliged to do it. That's something the question author should do, when noticing the migration. (There is inbox notification.)

If a tag you want does not exist in the site where your question was migrated to, and you lack the [Create new tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege, please follow the answer of [When should I create a new tag? How do I request a new tag if I don't have enough rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/when-should-i-create-a-new-tag-how-do-i-request-a-new-tag-if-i-dont-have-enoug).

Comment: As you're well aware and (I thought) generally practice, we, normally, close duplicate questions as duplicates, rather than answering them. I'm wondering why you chose to answer here rather than close as a duplicate? It doesn't really matter, but I am wondering.

Comment: @Makyen 1) I answered before it was closed, 2) I don't think it's really duplicate, this it specific enough to deserve its own answer.

Comment: Well, (1) is obvious, given the existence of this answer with collaboration from the timestamps. As for (2), the questions and issues raised in the question here are *explicitly* covered in the duplicates. Note: I agree that the linked duplicates weren't as clear and obvious regarding the information as they could have been, but that's something which indicates those primary sources should be edited (already done), rather than a new answer, which fragments information, created. What in this answer do you feel *isn't* covered in the two questions used as duplicate targets?

Comment: @Makyen it's not really about covered or not, it's about bringing it in a more focused way, that will make it easier for those having this exact issue, of tags being cleared after migration.